# How to get installtion size for script evaluation or custom components?

Tags: install4j

I need to check the disk space during a script/form component evaluation before I want to trigger an action. The standard installation directory dialog shows such an information but I do not find a possibility to get this information from the installer context at the script editor or custom component code. Is there a solution to get those information?

Thanks in advance.
Hardie

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [getTotalSize()](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/events/InstallerFileInstallationEvent.html#getTotalSize%28%29) for that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! It's not really practical for his purpose since it requires you to register an event listener. We'll add such a method to the context in a future version.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not in the API, but you can call

```
com.install4j.runtime.installer.helper.content.ContentInstaller.getInstance().getMinSize()
```

to get the size in bytes.